# Xamarin java binding ignores support jar

Tags: android, jar, xamarin

I need to use http://viewpagerindicator.com/ to add static tabs below the actionbar on a Xamarin.Android project.

I downloaded the project and migrated it from maven to gradle to build it into an AAR file suitable for Xamarin consumption. I created a java binding project, added the AAR file as a LibraryProjectZip and added the v13 support jar as a ReferenceJar but it seems it is being lost somewhere in the way as evidenced by these xbuild logs:

```
BINDINGSGENERATOR:  warning BG8C00: For type Com.Viewpagerindicator.IPageIndicator, base interface android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener does not exist.
BINDINGSGENERATOR:  warning BG8800: Unknown parameter type android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener in method SetOnPageChangeListener in managed type Com.Viewpagerindicator.IPageIndicator
BINDINGSGENERATOR:  warning BG8800: Unknown parameter type android.support.v4.view.ViewPager in method SetViewPager in managed type Com.Viewpagerindicator.IPageIndicator
```

The warnings chain continues for a long time, ending the process with a severely limited port
as the missing types make the methods depending on them to vanish away.

If i remove the support jar, the build fails because of missing classes from a utility named jar2xml, leading me to believe it is only used for part of the compilation/mapping process.

The support jar was taken from an unmodified android sdk at extras/android/support/v13/android-support-v13.jar.

Any help is most welcome.

Comment: Did you got the aar working? Thanks

Comment: Nope. Wound up using SlidingTabPager.Net

Answer (score 2):

There is a workaround to make these things work.

In my example, I had 2 reference jars (android-support-v4.jar and google-play-services.jar).
So if you just add these 2 jars with Build Action = ReferenceJar, you will see same errors as you posted.

```
BINDINGSGENERATOR:  warning BG8800: Unknown parameter type com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker in managed type Com.Google.Maps.Android.MarkerManager.
```

Though the Marker and MarkerManager classes are defined in the jars, they're not getting resolved correctly on the C# side. To fix that you need to do is to just add already compiled C# bindings for these jars as references.

In my case I used `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices` package which had a dependency `Xamarin.Android.Support.v4` (exactly as my jars).

In your case, you just need to add `Xamarin.Android.Support.v4` package to your binding project.

In the end you will have something like this in your project structure:

[image: Sample structure for Bindings project with same problem]

Hope that helps!